# No documentation found - Apipie

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, documentation

I am trying to run a production server. Almost everything is working but the documentation with Apipie does not work perfectly.

When I am in a development environment, everything is fine. But on production, Apipie does not find my documentation while my doc is written on each controller.

I think that is because Apipie is load before API controllers but I am not sure.

## initializer/apipie.rb

```
Apipie.configure do |config|
  config.app_name = "MyApi"
  config.api_base_url  = "/api"
  config.doc_base_url = "/Apidoc"
  config.validate = false
  config.layout = "api"
  config.markup = Apipie::Markup::Markdown.new
  config.reload_controllers = true if (Rails.env.development?)
  config.api_controllers_matcher = File.join(Rails.root, "app", "controllers", "api", "**","*.rb")
  config.app_info = <<-DOC
    This is where you can inform user about your application and API
    in general.
  DOC
end
```

## Gemfile.rb

```
gem 'apipie-rails'
gem 'maruku'
```

I am using Rails 4, Ruby 2.1, Apipie-Rails 0.0.22, Maruku 0.7.1

If anyone has an idea to unblock me, it would be very nice ! Thank you in advance.

**Edit :** I have created an **[issue](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails/issues/206)** on the github repository and it seems to be a problem coming from the gem itself

Comment: is your production environment on heroku?

Comment: Not yet, it is on a my own pre-production server. I have created a show project to show the problem. You can download it on the Guthub  [Issue#206](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails/issues/206).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution [here](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails/issues/206). I hope this will help someone else.

You just have to set your GemFile with the current repo and made the following modification on your initializer of Apipie :

`config.reload_controllers = true`

Like that, controllers are reloaded on every environments.